# How can we print docs from SWING application

Tags: java, swing, printing, operating-system

We have swing application. It includes documents(PDF, MSWord documents)
Can we call system's print dialog form our program to print this documents?

Target operating system is Windows XP.

And, id it is impossible, how can we process PDF and print PDF from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class (needs Java 6) if it is supported on your platform.
It has a `print` method for printing files (documents) if their type is registered with the system.

> Prints a file with the native desktop printing facility, using the associated application's print command.