# How do I print a text file in Java?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have a text editor that needs to print a text file. I want it to display a print preferences dialog, asking the user to select a printer, and paper settings, then print a file on the user's request.  I want this dialog's icon to be the same as my Swing application's icon, and ideally would like it to match my OS.

I looked at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184628) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184188/how-can-we-print-docs-from-swing-application) and tried to use `java.awt.print` but when I used it, all it did was pop up Windows Notepad, and immediately print to the default printer.  I want to user to be able to select a printer and other options before printing, so this was not a good method.

I then looked at the [Java print text tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html).  I came up with the code below:

```
try {
    boolean complete = TexType_Dark.textArea.print();
    if (complete) {
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TexType_Dark.frame, "Error while printing file.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

catch(PrinterException pe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TexType_Dark.frame, "Error while printing file.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
return;
```

This worked perfectly on the [Nimbus L&F](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/package-summary.html), but when running the [FlatLaf Dark Mac L&F](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf), the text was printed almost white (like it was on the component)! See result when using Microsoft Print to PDF:
[Screenshot of generated PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z80N2.png)

I want the printed text to always be black. Is there a way to do this?

For reference, I'm trying to print a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Comment: *"the text was printed almost white (like it was on the component)!"* - Then you need to change the component - or, make use of an "off screen" varient which renders the text as it would appear on a white background

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have used `printTextArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);` but this affects only the background color, not the text color.

Comment: `setForeground` - this will change the text color

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) and develop your own `Printable` workflow ... but having done something simular recently, I'd consider this a "last ditch effort" scenario

Comment: @MadProgrammer Post your comments as an answer so I can mark them as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was `textArea.setForeground();`.
Thanks @MadProgrammer for the answer.